# How many A is needed to be B number of results with a C probability?

Tags: probability

I am able to perform action XYZ once a week. The success rate of action XYZ is 15%. If I want XYZ to exceed 5 times, what is the expected number of weeks it'll take?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Negative Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).

The probability the action succeeds is 15%, and you are repeating this action until you observe 5 successes. This corresponds to parameter values $p=0.15$ and $r=5$.

The expected number of weeks is, thus, $r/p=33.\overline{3}$.